# Why do some laptops not have a GPU slot?

Tags: laptop, gpu

I got an i7 Dell laptop but it doesn’t have any GPU slots. I just want to know why laptop manufacturers don't add GPU slots (since users may need a GPU upgrade at any time). How much extra does it cost manufacturers to add a graphics card slot?

Comment: If all manufacturers were making laptops just for you, then they would all have GPU slots. But they aren’t. They are making laptops for everyone, with all different shapes, sizes, features and prices. Almost nobody knows what a “GPU upgrade” is, nor do they need one.

Comment: Most people don’t laptops for GPU performance. Desktop PCs have always been seen as the home of GPU upgradability.

Comment: Modern laptops are packed tightly inside, like how a phone is assembled. Otherwise how can you have thin laptops? That means there's zero space for an external GPU. People need flexibility and mobility for those laptops, so no one cares about graphics performance because they don't do 3D rendering or gaming on the laptop anyway. That said there are laptops with MXM graphics cards, mainly gaming ones, and obviously they're not as light and mobile as others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laptops generally do not come with GPU slots because they are very proprietary in size and dimensions. When a laptop does have a dedicated GPU, it's more than likely soldered to the motherboard.

Due to the different layouts and the way laptops are built, you generally can't upgrade the GPU in a laptop. In some cases, you can replace the one you have, with the exact same kind.

There are some exceptions, because a few laptops use a [Mobile PCIE Express Module (MXM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_PCI_Express_Module) slot. There is also the possibility that a laptop may have an [ExpressCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExpressCard) slot, which would allow the use of an external graphics card.

Laptops lack the ability to easily upgrade hardware like desktops. 99% of the time, your laptop is limited to upgrading RAM and swapping out an HDD with an SSD. If you're wanting to upgrade the CPU or graphics, it's most likely not going to happen. Your only option would be buying a new laptop.